# Apache Rewrite Mod

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am trying to achieve virtual subdomain as my hosting provider has set a limitation on the number of subdomains I can have! I already have a wildcard DNS entry so all subdomains are accepted and send to the root of my domain. Here's what I have put in .htaccess to handle the redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|admin).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.domain\.-com
RewriteCond /home/username/public_html/subdomain/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /home/username/public_html/subdomain/%1/$1
```

The problem is in the last line which does the actual redirection, the server shows a 500 (Internal server error), but the apache error log does not expand the error. In its place if I put something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?path=/home/username/public_html/subdomain/%1/$1
```

It works fine... And the path is the correct file path.

Comment: Final solution: `RewriteEngine on
# first prevent recursion
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
# second handle subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|admin)\.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteCond /home/username/public_html/subdomain/%1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/%1/$1 [L]`

Comment: hi GKK, can you update your Question with your comment, or add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although its late, but here's the full answer to my question. It's a pretty handy script if you ever run out of subdomains.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[www|admin] [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/%1/$1 [L]
```

Note the actual URL for: http://virtual.domain.com/index.php will be http://www.domain.com/subdomain/virtual/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to:

- first test if it's a subdomain (like you do) and if so make your tests on /subdomain/(realsubdomain)
- then if it's (www or admin) then refuse everything that tries to access to /subdomain/xxx

Note that I've removed (`/home/username/public_html`)

So this should be close to:

```
RewriteEngine on
# first handle subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|admin)\.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteCond /home/username/public_html/subdomain/%1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/%1/$1
# then in main domains:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|admin)\.* [NC]
# ...refuse access to subdomain:
RewriteRule ^/subdomain(.*) - [R=404,L]
```

NB: this is a 404 redirect, so you could make your own 404 at the very beginning of the rewriterules, something like:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /404.php - [QSA,L]
... blabla...
```

And in your 404.php handle the URL to display some nice message :)

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: @Oliver Even this: `RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/%1/$1` throws a 500 HTTP error! I cannot understand this issue logically because if I can write `RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php` then `RewriteRule (.*) subdomain/%1/$1` (no leading /) should work !

Comment: I've added my two usual "hints", could you please add rewrite log in your question to see what's going on? Thanks

Comment: @Oliver: Thanks a lot for your help..! Since this setup is on a shared hosting server, I cannot have RewriteLog enabled there, so I have set up a similar environment on my system. The problem is that it gets stuck in an infinite loop and keeps adding /subdomain/.. to every request and hence the 500 error.

Comment: @Oliver: I have figured it out! Adding `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` as the first condition prevents the rewrite loop which solves the problem.

Comment: @GKK Okay I didn't know about the REDIRECT_STATUS environment variable ;) Glad to help anyway!